# Accessing a property elsewhere in the tree

Tags: xslt

**Background context**

I work in Microsoft Azure DevOps, a web-based project management service. The service lets you write XSLT templates to export some information to Word in custom formats. I am not well-versed in XSLT at all.

I need to access properties of an element of my data structure. The problem is that the element can be seen at two different places in the tree and these do not have parent/child relationships.

**Data structure**

Please see in the picture below. At the `planAndSuites/testPlan/suiteHierarchy/suite` level, you will see that suite 9506 is the parent of suites 9507, 9508, 9509 etc. The IDs happen to be sequential but that is not always true. There could also be more levels of suites (the bottom level could have children of its own, and all the following levels would be called 'suite')

If you look to `planAndSuites/testSuites/testSuite` you will find the same suite ID numbers: 9506, 9507, 9508, etc. This time, the suites have testCase information attached to them.

[image]

**What I want**

I want to access the testCase information, but I also want the output to show the parent/child hierarchy levels. My code outputs the hierarchy, but how do I ALSO access the data present in `planAndSuites/testSuites/testSuite` when in a for-each based on `planAndSuites/testPlan/suiteHierarchy/suite` *considering the ID will always match*.

**What I have**

Current Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="planAndSuites" >
      <div id="exported-data">

        <xsl:for-each select="testSuites">
          <xsl:for-each select="testSuite">
            <br/>
            Test Suite: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> 
            PARENT SUITE: 
            <br/><hr/>           
            <xsl:for-each select="testCases">
                <xsl:for-each select="testCase">
                    Test case: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>  - <xsl:value-of select="@title"/> 
                    <br/> 
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Desired Output:**

Same as output pictured, except `PARENT SUITE:` should show (none) for 9506, and it should show 9506 for the others.

Comment: So it should show the same `Test Suite: 9506` for every item?

Comment: @zx485 With the data I put in my question, yes, except for 9506 because it doesn't have a parent. In reality I have more data, sometimes the parent will not be 9506.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a key `<xsl:key name="suite-ref" match="planAndSuites/testPlan/suiteHierarchy//suite" use="@id"/>` as a top level element of the stylesheet and then use `PARENT SUITE: <xsl:value-of select="key('suite-ref', @id)/parent::suite/@id"/>`.

Comment: Hi Martin, this works however I don't understand why. Could you explain how the second code line works please?

Comment: The `xsl:key` declaration is a hint/request to the XSLT processor to index the matched `planAndSuites/testPlan/suiteHierarchy//suite` elements by their `id` attribute value. That way then the `key` function called with an appropriate id value efficiently finds a referenced element. So `key('suite-ref', @id)` in the context of the `testSuite` gives us the related `suite` with the same `id` and then you said you want to navigate up to the parent `suite` and output its `id` attribute, so in XPath `parent::suite/@id`, all in one expression `key('suite-ref', @id)/parent::suite/@id`.

Comment: This is all elementary and basic XPath and XSLT stuff found in existing tutorials and books, like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `(none)` entry with an `xsl:choose`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="testSuites">
  <xsl:for-each select="testSuite">
    <br/>
    Test Suite: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> 
    PARENT SUITE: 
    <br/><hr/> 
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(testCases) = 0">
        (none)
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:for-each select="testCases">
            <xsl:for-each select="testCase">
                Test case: <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>  - <xsl:value-of select="@title"/> 
                <br/> 
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but some suites will not have a test case, but that does not mean they won't have a parent. Child/parent hierarchy is not dependent on the count of testCases. It is dependant on the suiteHierarchy part of the tree, which is outside the testSuite part of the tree which I'm currently in.